# sum 2 variables in a bash script within telnet

Tags: bash, networking, arithmetic

I am writing a script which should listen on a specific port and once somebody connects to it via that port (through telnet), it should ask for 2 numbers and return their sum. Like when I type telnet [my_server] [my_port] it asks for 2 numbers and then prints their sum.

My situation is that it just doesn't print the sum no matter which commands or syntax I've used.

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -v -l -p 3360 -c 'echo Enter num1:
read num1
echo Enter num2:
read num2
echo "$(($num1+$num2))"'
```

Comment: `nc: invalid option -- 'c'` - what version of nc are you using ?

Comment: -c is for being able to write commands within nc (according to nc -- help: "-c Executes the given commands via /bin/sh").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

add_num()
{
echo Enter num1:
read num1
echo Enter num2:
read num2
echo $(( $(echo $num1 | tr -d '\r') + $(echo $num2 | tr -d '\r') ))
}

rm -f /tmp/f; mkfifo /tmp/f
cat /tmp/f | add_num 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
```

This should work...
The -c option in not supported with nc & it is stated in man pages we should use above syntax.
Also, we have to truncate the carriage return that comes with input from telnet ..

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that works great thank you! why all the other methods don't work and this one does?

Answer (score 0):

There exist several incompatible implementations of `nc`/`netcat`. I'd use `socat` here:

```
socat 'tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr' system:\''
  printf "num1: "
  read x
  printf "num2: "
  read y
  echo "$((x + y))"'\'
```

Beware that `telnet` will send the lines as `123\r\n`, so `123\r` will be stored in the variables causing arithmetic syntax errors.

Instead of `telnet localhost 1234`, you can use:

```
socat - tcp:localhost:1234
```

Or you can strip the CRs with:

```
socat 'tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr' system:$'\'
  printf "num1: "
  read x
  printf "num2: "
  read y
  echo "$((${x%\r} + ${y%\r}))"\''
```

If you want to be able to handle more than one incoming connection, add the `fork` option to the first address.

If you want the shell errors to be sent to the client, add the `stderr` option to the second address.

So combining both:

```
socat tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork system:\''
  printf "num1: "
  read x
  printf "num2: "
  read y
  echo "$((x + y))"'\',stderr
```

Above, the code would be interpreted by your system's `sh`. To use another interpreter and any arbitrary code (without having to worry if it contains single quotes or commas for instance), you can do:

```
CODE=$(cat << 'EOF'
printf 'num1: '
read x
printf 'num2: '
read y
x=${x%$'\r'}
y=${y%$'\r'}
echo "$((x + y))"
EOF
) socat tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork exec:\''bash -c "eval \\"$CODE\\""'\'
```